# php are array elements accessed by reference?

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

The title of the question might hard to interpret, the following is the code that might help

```
$containers = array(); // array of arrays
for ($index = 0; $index < 4; $index++) {
  $containers[] = array(); // each element of the array is an array
}

foreach ($objects as $object) {
  $index = computeIndex($object); // compute the index into the $containers
  $container = $containers[$index]; // get the subarray object
  $container[] = $object; // append $object to the end of the subarray
  $containers[$index] = $container; // <--- question: is this needed?
}
```

So as the question shows, do I still need to reassign the subarray back to the array? If its a reference of the element in the array, then I don't think I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the last line is needed; array elements are stored as values rather than references.  However, PHP will allow you to create a reference with [`&`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php):

```
$container = &$containers[$index];
$container[] = $object;
```

You could also save yourself some trouble and just do:

```
$containers[$index][] = $object;
```

Comment: awesome! do I still need the first loop for initializing the $containers?

Comment: You do, but you could probably use array_fill instead